# “EXC_BAD_ACCESS: Unable to restore previously selected frame” - stack variables not getting cleaned up

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4.2, internal

With reference to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051790/exc-bad-access-unable-to-restore-previously-selected-frame-error-array-size).

The solutions provided in that thread, include:

1. Being smart about where and how many variables you declare, that would go on the stack.
2. Disable Guard Malloc if needed.

Also, in general:
3. Make sure you are releasing a variable you have actually allocated memory for!!

I have none of the above issues. There are very few stack-allocated variables that I use within functions, say 2-3 within each. But because the functions are called in a loop several times, it seems to trigger an exception.

And here's the kicker, this is not just happening for statically allocated variables, but stuff on the heap too! I'm getting the page errors on Auto-released declarations of NSNumber variables that I use a couple of inside the loop, as well as a dictionary that I juDIciously alloc and release within the scope of the function, every single time it's called.

So why is this happening, and why the heck are heap variables getting affected? I don't get it at all, please throw some light on this. :)

I'm on IOS5 with XCode 4.2, iPhone/iPad simulator.

Thanks!

Regards,
Dev

**Edit: Sample code**


`- (void)doSomething {

   NSInteger fun = 3;

   NSInteger time = 4;

   NSInteger overload = fun*time;

   NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",overload];

   NSObject *myCustomObject = [[NSObject alloc] init];

   [myCustomDictionary setObject:myCustomObject forKey:string];

   [myCustomObject release];

   //myCustomDictionary is an iVar, alloced in the class's init method, and released in dealloc and not touched anywhere in between

}

//doSomething gets called several times through the course of execution as the state of the view changes, the user interacts with it etc, often 2-3 times during one state change.`

The code is purposely vague, but at the same time, it is EXACTLY as simple as in the sample. As is the rest of the code in the entire project. Several functions, each doing a small amount of work, as nicely self contained memory-wise as this one.

I faced EXC_BAD_ACCESS issues before, and at that point had referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051790/exc-bad-access-unable-to-restore-previously-selected-frame-error-array-size) question. However in my case, I was not creating multiple variables on the stack within a loop, they were getting created repeatedly by a function which gets called several times through the course of the execution. Ideally, the variables should have just got destroyed at the end of function-scope. Not sure why that didn't happen.

Anyway, to resolve that and to prevent multiple allocations from happening, I ended up declaring my stack-allocated variables as all `static`. That is bad practice, but that's exactly what I had to do to get it working. And it was working until I ended up facing the issue AGAIN with the "doSomething" function.

So the difficulty in "doSomething", was that I did not have only stack-allocated variables getting created, but heap stuff too. So I first started getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS on the NSInteger variables, at which point I tried fixing it again, by declaring them as static. It worked, but now EXC_BAD_ACCESS started occurring on the auto-released variable and finally the custom-allocated variable - which is when I got stumped. I have been following all the rules of memory management, and I'm having stack AND heap variables fubaring all over me. If it was only heap stuff, or stack stuff inside a loop, I could understand there's a mistake SOMEwhere. But here, it's neither, these are perfectly innocent variables getting allocated on the stack inside ONE function that is NOT called in a loop, and regular auto-released variables that never ever get retains or releases thrown at them from another place in the code. What makes it all even worse, is that the failure points are random - not just in this function but practically every one that gets called several times through the course of execution of the project.

**Edit2:** Turns out, in this case, it's my fault. See my answer for details. Sorry for wasting people's time. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah geez I don't believe this.

The issues faced earlier with the stack-allocated NSInteger variables holds, but in this case, it was entirely my fault.

"doSomething" was part of a long chain of events, that, due to some silly negligence on my part, ends up looping a bunch of times, which is what, rightfully and as it should be, leads to the application running out of memory. Whether it's with the stack variables or with the malloced ones sitting on the heap, with an infinite loop, it's gonna crash one way or another. :)

So the crash is perfectly fair, just got confused in this case with a previous issue that turned out to be unrelated. :(

Sorry for wasting everybody's time.

Answer (score 1):

We can't really help you without seeing the whole stack trace.
`EXC_BAD_ACCESS` doesn't mean anything in order to troubleshoot we need to know what the exception is.

Based on my experience when you don't get a stack tarce it means you are double releasing. Zombies is the way to find your double release.

Go to: `Product -> Profile` and then select "`Zombies`" from the list.
Run the app and perform any task that causes the crash, if the problem is a double release a pop-up would appear. Select the arrow in the popup and it tells you exactly what object is being double released, and it shows you the retain cycle.

Comment: Please refer my answer. I'm unable to accept it right now, as it seems I can only accept my own answer after 2 days of asking the question, or something like that.

Comment: And as I have mentioned, Zombies would be applicable for objects declared on the heap. I was facing the same issue with STACK variables too, so it was not a retain/release issue, as much as it was that the app was just running out of memory after x iterations of an infinite loop, as clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without any code posted in your question, and seeing that you are using iOS 5 and Xcode 4.2 my best advice for you is, in Xcode, go to `Edit>Refactor>Convert to Objective-C ARC` and wave all your memory management headaches goodbye.

ARC does all the memory management for you. You do not need to retain, release or write dealloc methods. You don't have to worry about memory management in most cases. You will leave mysterious `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` crashes behind. The way it works is super efficient. The compiler puts in the retains and releases for you and then optimises. You never even have to see the code.

Comment: The problems have to do with both statically allocated objects and purely auto-released objects, and not custom-released ones so to speak, so I doubt ARC will help. I can edit the question with some sample code if that helps.